# How to check the permission whether a friend allow me to post on his wall or not using php sdk

Tags: php, facebook

I have created an app that needs to check whether a friend allows a user to post on his/her wall or not before posting content on friend's wall. This scenario is required because I need to disable the submit button when the user chooses that friend to post the content if the user doesn't have permission.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask for `publish_stream` permissions when someone uses your app. These links give more info.

PHP SDK http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

FB permissions: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Tutorial for connecting to FB including asking for permissions: http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-3-0-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/

If you need further help, please ask more specific questions as it is very difficult to give helpful answers to vague questions such as this.